# A tool to replace Sublime SFTP's "Monitor file (upload on external save)" functionality?

Tags: sftp, sublimetext, sublimetext3, codekit

I am heavily using Sublime SFTP's "Monitor file (upload on external save)" feature in combination with CodeKit for a "semi-local" developing workflow (files and git are local, but everything is ran remotely).

Each time CodeKit compiles a file, Sublime SFTP uploads the output to the development web server.

But Sublime SFTP keeps forgetting it's monitoring tasks, it's not very reliable.

Is there another tool that simply watches a file and uploads it on change? Can be command line too.

PS I've been to http://css-tricks.com/deployment/ - there is a Grunt Add-On that would do this. But as I'm using CodeKit, I guess that's not suitable.

Comment: Maybe a hook in codekit could be set up - http://css-tricks.com/codekit-2-0/ to scp the file(s)

Comment: Although partially referring to mac only software, i have not posted this on AskDifferent, as the tags are only available here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

Having set up ssh set up with `ssh-copy-id`, registering a Hook in CodeKit to call scp works.

[image]

```
scp ~/mylocalprojects/path/to/main.css user@server.com:/home/user/public_html/path/to/main.css
```

Great!

Comment: It should work, but it's not really robust. Now tampering with `gulp-sftp` for the same purpose